# Como criar uma propriedade num objeto existente de uma requisição http?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http-request

Estou tentando exaustivamente colocar uma propriedade num objeto que vem de uma requisição (JSON), mas não estou conseguindo, é como se ele só não colocasse, porém quando eu faço um console.log, lá está ela, mas ele não está retornando na resposta que eu envio para o postman.

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    let result = JSON.parse(body);
    result['teste'] = 'teste';
    res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

Sem a propriedade ele me retorna assim:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "prop1",
        "prop2": "prop2",
    },
    {
        "prop1": "prop1",
        "prop2": "prop2",
    },
]
```

E eu queria que com o código ele me retornasse algo assim:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "prop1",
        "prop2": "prop2",
    },
    {
        "prop1": "prop1",
        "prop2": "prop2",
    },
    "teste": "teste",
]
```

Como eu faço para ficar dessa maneira acima?

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer depois de atribuir a propriedade? Uma nova requisição?

Comment: @bfavaretto estou pegando um json externo de outra url, quero só adicionar uma propriedade e retornar para o usuário como resposta da requisição.

Comment: O que é "retornar para o usuário"? Seu código trata o retorno desse JSON e acrescenta uma propriedade no objeto obtido. O uso do objeto precisa ser feito de dentro dessa função (callback) que você já tem.

Comment: @bfavaretto esse código é uma parte de uma api, no caso, fazemos requisição pra essa rota que vai buscar uma informação em uma api externa que retorna um json para mim, eu preciso tratar adicionando um campo extra no fim do json como no exemplo e retornar o json modificado.

Comment: @Lollorcaust já tentou `result.push({teste: 'teste'});` ?

Answer (score 4):

Você transformou a string em objeto.

Precisa transformar em string de novo antes de enviar:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    let result = JSON.parse(body);
    result['teste'] = 'teste';
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Manual:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, ele só não põe o elemento na resposta.

Comment: Aí o problema pode ser o fato da sua requisição não estar chamando o request( ). Tem certeza que seu código está rodando de fato, e a requisição passa por ele? Ponha instruções de LOG no meio, e confira.

Comment: Sim, eu verifiquei e ele entra dentro da função, inclusive cheguei a imprimir só o result['teste'] e ele imprime. O Estranho também é que se eu retornar ao invés ali de result, retornar result['teste'] ele retorna a propriedade teste certinha no postman.

Comment: Também tentei mudar a lib, ao invés do request, usar o axios, mas acontece a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

O retorno da API é um array, para adicionar um novo elemento, utilizasse o método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

#### Exemplo funcionando:

```js
let result = JSON.parse('[{"prop1":"prop1","prop2":"prop2"},{"prop1":"prop1","prop2":"prop2"}]');
result.push({teste: 'teste'});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

#### Como você esta tentando:

```js
let result = JSON.parse('[{"prop1":"prop1","prop2":"prop2"},{"prop1":"prop1","prop2":"prop2"}]');
result['teste'] = 'teste';
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

desse jeito irá funcionar se o retorno for um objeto:

```js
let result = JSON.parse('{"prop1":"prop1","prop2":"prop2"}');
result['teste'] = 'teste';
// ou
result.testeB = 'teste b';
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```